# C# Winforms: Attach Scrollbar to Control

Tags: c#, winforms, controls, scrollbar

I have a custom Winforms control for which I would like to add scrolling, so I simply added a `VScrollBar` to its right. However, when my custom control is selected, and the user scrolls the mouse, nothing happens (since my custom control does not inherently allow scrolling).

How do I "attach" the `VScrollBar` to my control so that scrolling when the custom control is focused actually scrolls the `VScrollBar`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you have to ensure that your custom control is focused (any child control inside it will be OK):

```
//inside your custom control class
protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseEventArgs e){
   vScrollBar1.Value += e.Delta > 0 ?  -vScrollBar1.LargeChange : vScrollBar1.LargeChange;
}
```